# N-bit serial adder/subtractor VHDL

Tags: logic, vhdl

I'm trying to implement a serial adder/subtractor in VHDL, I've done it the ripple carry way before but now I'm supposed to implement the same functionality by just using one full adder cell instead of N-amount of cells so I have to shift the bits from the vectors in to the full adder/subtractor and store the result in another vector which I just shift the index for as well... The logic behind it is very easily understood, you just have a counter for the index and so on. But I obviously encounter problems since I'm probably still thinking a bit too much software programming I guess...

The problem I have is that the counter increases to 1 right away when it enters the process so that when I try to add the vectors a = 0101 0101 and b = 1010 1010 I get y = 1111 111X and the carrys = 0000 000X. I've tried to start storing the result at index_counter - 1 since the index jumps to 1 on the first clock cycle, but then I get a fatal error in the simulation...

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours now and can't seem to figure out how to do it, so could you please take a look and see what I can do to fix it? Would be very much appreciated!

I do have signals for saturation and overflow that I am going to implement later on but they aren't really used at the moment so don't worry about them.

The design shouldn't update the final result before the addition/subtraction is finished if you're wondering why I have done it the way I have..

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity serial_adder_subtracter_saturate is
    generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8);
    port (a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          b : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          saturate : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
          add_sub : IN STD_LOGIC := '1';
          clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
          start : IN STD_LOGIC;
          reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
          y : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          overflow : OUT STD_LOGIC;
          finished : OUT STD_LOGIC);
end serial_adder_subtracter_saturate;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF serial_adder_subtracter_saturate is

component bitAdder is
port(a : IN STD_LOGIC;
     b : IN STD_LOGIC;
     cin : IN STD_LOGIC;
     add_sub : IN STD_LOGIC;
     y : OUT STD_LOGIC;
     cout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal carry : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- hold the carry outs from the adders
signal temp_sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal o_flow : STD_LOGIC;      -- internal overflow signal so I can read it in the process

signal a_temp : STD_LOGIC;
signal b_temp : STD_LOGIC;
signal y_temp : STD_LOGIC;
signal cin_temp : STD_LOGIC; 
signal cout_temp : STD_LOGIC;

begin 
AddSub: bitAdder 
    port map(a => a_temp, 
             b => b_temp, 
             cin => cin_temp, 
             add_sub => add_sub, 
              y => y_temp, 
             cout => cout_temp);

    o_flow <= carry(WIDTH-1) XOR carry(WIDTH-2);

test: process(clk)
variable index_counter : integer range 0 to (WIDTH) := 0;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if reset = '1' then
            index_counter := 0;
            carry <= (others => '0');
            temp_sum <= (others => '0');
            finished <= '0';
        elsif reset = '0' AND start = '1' then
            if index_counter = (WIDTH) then
                finished <= '1';
                y <= temp_sum;
            else
                if index_counter = 0 then
                    cin_temp <= NOT add_sub;
                else
                    cin_temp <= carry(index_counter);
                end if;

                a_temp <= a(index_counter);
                b_temp <= b(index_counter);
                carry(index_counter) <= cout_temp;
                temp_sum(index_counter) <= y_temp;

                index_counter := index_counter + 1;
            end if;             
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end behavior;
```

Here's how the full adder/subtractor looks if that's of interest:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY bitAdder IS
    PORT (a: IN STD_LOGIC;
          b: IN STD_LOGIC;
          cin: IN STD_LOGIC;
          add_sub : IN STD_LOGIC;
          y: OUT STD_LOGIC;
          cout: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END bitAdder;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF bitAdder IS
signal b_sig : STD_LOGIC := '1';
BEGIN
    b_sig <= not b when add_sub = '0' else
                 b;             -- b_sig <= add_sub XOR b;
    y <= a XOR b_sig XOR cin;
    cout <= (a AND b_sig) OR 
            (b_sig AND cin) OR 
            (a AND cin);
END behavior;
```

Comment: If you don't want us to worry about a part of your code, then please remove that part. It is considered polite and helpful to post a minimal, working example that illustrates your question; not just dump your source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to debug this, but I think it is a timing problem:

At the very first rising clock edge, you define both the inputs to your adder **and** register the adder's outputs (which are X at this point, because its inputs weren't defined before).

With the idea of storing the result at `index_counter - 1` you are on the right track however you need to take care that you never try to store the result in a non-existing register such as `carry(-1)` or `temp_sum(-1)`. You can use `if index_counter > 0` for that for example.

Similarly, you then need to allow for one more cycle at the end of the calculation or assign the last result bit directly to your `y` output or you'll miss the last result bit.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yea thanks that fixed the problem, had to do an extra cycle and put some code in for not going outside the index range.. Looks like shit but it does what it should.